# ADB2C Custom Policy - validate a claim against a string value always returns true

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am having an id_token_hint from which I am reading an extension attribute to check if the role is Admin and if so not to issue (skip) token.

To check if the user is Admin I am doing the following

```
    <ClaimType Id="isAdmin">
    <DisplayName>Verify if user is Admin User</DisplayName>
    <DataType>boolean</DataType>
    <UserHelpText>Verify if user is Admin User</UserHelpText>
    </ClaimType>
```

Claim Transformation

```
    <ClaimsTransformation Id="isAdminUser" TransformationMethod="CompareClaimToValue">
    <InputClaims>
      <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_role" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim1" />
    </InputClaims>
    <InputParameters>
      <InputParameter Id="compareTo" DataType="string" Value="Super Admin" />
      <InputParameter Id="operator" DataType="string" Value="equal" />
      <InputParameter Id="ignoreCase" DataType="string" Value="true" />
    </InputParameters>
    <OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="isAdmin" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />
    </OutputClaims>
    </ClaimsTransformation>
```

UserJourney

```
    <OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <Preconditions>
         <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
           <Value>isAdminUser</Value>
           <Value>False</Value>
           <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
         </Precondition>
      </Preconditions>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="AdminUserNotAllowed" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AdminUserNotAllowed" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>
```

The issue is that this condition returns true for all users (non-Admin aswell) .

From App insights :

```
    Claims 
email: myadmin@mailinator.com 
errorMessage: Admin user access via SignIn link is not allowed. Please access the application via normal SignIn 
extension_role: Super Admin
    
    Claims 
email: myorgadmin@abc.com 
errorMessage: Admin user access via SignIn link is not allowed. Please access the application via normal SignIn 
extension_role: Organization Admin RW
```

To clarify my requirement is

```
if (extension_role === "Super Admin")
   //Do not allow magic signIn
```

I have tried initially ClaimEquals but that had also returned true in all cases.

```
<OrchestrationStep Order="6" Type="ClaimsExchange">
  <Preconditions>
    <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="tru">
      <Value>extension_role</Value>
      <Value>Super Admin</Value>
      <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
    </Precondition>
  </Preconditions>
  <ClaimsExchanges>
    <ClaimsExchange Id="SelfAssertedAgencyNotMatched" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAssertedAgencyNotMatched" />
  </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like [this](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/issue-with-claimequals-in-azure-ad-b2c-3554c4546a6).

This uses TransformationMethod="CompareClaims",

Comment: I had reviewed the same and I thought my case fell in "So “canned” values are OK" but I could not make it working. Italways returns true extension_role = "Super Admin" . Referring to the latest doc I thought it was correct for this transform (compareclaimtovalue) - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/string-transformations#example-of-compareclaimtovalue . But this also returns true in all the cases. Is it because of space in the string value?

Comment: Why does the code set a boolean called "isAdmin" and then check for "isAdminUser"?

Comment: I was able to compare the static string based on - https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/issue-with-claimequals-in-azure-ad-b2c-3554c4546a6. Thank you.